# How many five-digit numbers can be made from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$, provided that each digit can be repeated twice?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, combinations

The 10,000th place can be filled in $4$ different ways, the 1000th place can be filled in $5$ different ways, the 100th place can be filled in $4$ different ways, seeing the double repetition of numerical values, and the 10th and 1st places must be filled $(5-2)=3$ different ways each. Thus, the total number of possible such 5-digit numbers is $4 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 720$.
However, i found the following solution:
$$1) 1\cdot5!/1=120$$
$$2) 5\cdot5!/2=300$$
$$3) 10\cdot5!/4=300$$
$1)$ understandable. The number of all possible choices with zero in any position.
$1) 2)$ already incomprehensible. In theory, you need to calculate how many numbers there will be so that there is no zero in front. After all, such numbers are invalid. And somehow calculate, the number of options with repeating numbers $2$ times. Could you explain this to me?

Comment: Hint = What a beautiful question to use exponential generating functions

Comment: Do you mean each digit can be repeated a maximum of 2 times?

Comment: Their solution allows zeroes in any position which is usually not how you would do.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Yes, I think so.

Comment: Their first term is where there is no digit repeating, second is where they are selecting one from $1-5$ and third is where they are selecting two from $1-5$ that are repeating

Comment: Even with that they seem to have problems with their solution though

Comment: @Math Lover What do you mean?

Comment: Take $2) 5\cdot5!/2=300$ for example. They are choosing one of the five given digits to repeat but now that one of the digits repeats twice, we are left with choosing only three more digits from remaining four. There are $4C3$ ways to choose three digits, correct? Once we have the digits, we permute in $5! / 2!$ ways.

Comment: @Math Lover Yeah, it should be 0:  1⋅1⋅5!/1=120 
1:  5⋅4⋅5!/2=1200 
2:  10⋅3⋅5!/4=900 
Total:  2220

Comment: you are absolutely correct. $2220$ is the correct solution if we allow zero in the first place.

Comment: @Math Lover Forbidding leading zeros would result into 1776, well i used python, so it's kinda unfair )

Comment: Yes that is correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If leading zero is allowed, the count of numbers with given constraints is $2220$ as you mentioned in the comments. But if we only consider actual five digit numbers, you can either subtract all numbers with leading zero meeting other constraints from $2220$. Here is another way to go about it -

a) The most significant digit does not repeat -

- $4$ ways to choose the most significant digit

i) two digits repeat

- $\displaystyle {4\choose 2}$ ways to choose digits to repeat and $\dfrac{4!}{2! \ 2!}$ ways to permute them.

ii) one digit repeats

- $4$ ways to choose the digit to repeat and $3$ ways to choose $2$ remaining digits and permute them in  $\dfrac{4!}{2!}$.

iii) No repetition

- All digits must be chosen and they can be permuted in $4!$ ways.

b) The most significant digit repeats -

- again, $4$ ways to choose the most significant digit

i) two digits repeat

- we choose another digit to repeat in $4$ ways and another digit from remaining $3$ digits in $3$ ways and then permute them in $\dfrac{4!}{2!}$ ways.

ii) only one digit repeats

- we choose three digits from remaining $4$ digits in $4$ ways and permute them in $4!$ ways.

So total number of ways =

$ \displaystyle 4 \cdot \left[{4\choose 2} \frac{4!}{2! \; 2!} + 4 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} + 4! + 4 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{4!}{2!} + 4 \cdot 4!\right] = 1776$

Comment: very perfect +1

Answer (score 3):

$\color{red}{HINT=}$There are three situation such that zero is used once , zero is used two times  and zero is not used.

Zero is not used : Our generaitng function is $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2})^4$ , then find the coefficient of $x^5$ and multiply it by $5!$

Zero is used once= Our generating function is $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2})^4$ , then find the coefficient of $x^4$ and multiply it by $4!$. After that select one place for $0$ among $4$ suitable place.

Zero is used two times = Our generating function is $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2})^4$ , then find the coefficient of $x^3$ and multiply it by $3!$. After that select two place for $0$ among $3$ suitable place.

$\color{blue}{OR}$,

More concisely, Lets think all of arrangement where zero may be leadind digit such that $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2})^5$ , then find the coefficient of $x^5$ and multiply it by $5!$.

Now we should subtract the cases where zero is leading digit such that $(1+ x+ \frac{x^2}{2})^4 \times (1+x)$ , then find the coefficient of $x^4$ and multiply it by $4!$.

At last , subtract these two cases . Then you will find the number of $5$ digits numbers where it does not start with $0$ and each terms repeat at most $2$ times.

Comment: this is good. pls check if you get $1776$ without leading zeroes. Taking example of  leading zero not allowed, here is how I would set up -

Comment: i) for numbers where most significant digit does not repeat - take coefficient of $x^4 \ in \ \left(1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)^4 $

Comment: ii) for numbers where most significant digit repeats - take coefficient of $x^4 \ in \ x \cdot \left (1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2}\right)^4$

Comment: After adding them, multiply by $4$ given choices for leftmost digit and by $4!$ to permute remaining four digits.

Comment: @MathLover I checked in wolfram and it gives $2220$ for leading is zero and $1776$ for leading is not zero

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about generating functions.  I can't resist the alternative approach of taking off my shoes.

Assumed that constraints mean that :

- Leftmost digit can't be $(0)$.
- Each number can be repeated **at most** two times.

---

Then, the following 7 mutually exclusive cases need to be considered:

Case 1: No $(0)$ is used, and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-2-1. 
Case 2: No $(0)$ is used and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-1-1-1.

Case 3: 1 $(0)$ is used, and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-2-1. 
Case 4: 1 $(0)$ is used, and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-1-1-1. 
Case 5: 1 $(0)$ is used, and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 1-1-1-1-1.

Case 6: 2 $(0)$'s are used, and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-2-1. 
Case 7: 2 $(0)$'s are used and the distribution of numbers used has the pattern 2-1-1-1.

I will let $T_k$ denote the enumeration for Case $k$. 
Therefore, the final enumeration will be $T_1 + \cdots + T_7.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1: No (0), pattern = 2,2,1}}$

There are $\binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}$ choices for the two numbers that will be duplicated, and then the 3rd number that will appear as a singleton.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{1,1,2,2,3\}$, then there are $\binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2}$ ways of placing these numbers.

$T_1 = 6 \times 2 \times 5 \times 6 = 360$.

$\underline{\text{Case 2: No (0), pattern = 2,1,1,1}}$

There are $\binom{4}{1}$ choices for the specific number that will be duplicated.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{1,1,2,3,4\}$, then there are $\binom{5}{2} \times 3!$ ways of placing these numbers.

$T_2 = 4 \times 10 \times 3! = 240$.

$\underline{\text{Case 3: 1 (0), pattern = 2,2,1}}$

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ choices for the two non-zero  numbers that will be duplicated.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{0,1,1,2,2\}$, then there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of placing the $0$.  Once the $0$ is placed, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of placing the non-zero numbers.

$T_3 = 6 \times 4 \times 6 = 144$.

$\underline{\text{Case 4: 1 (0), pattern = 2,1,1,1}}$

There are $\binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1}$ choices for the non-zero  number that will be duplicated and the non-zero number that will be omitted.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{0,1,1,2,3\}$, then there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways of placing the $0$.  Once the $0$ is placed, there are $(4 \times 3)$ ways of placing the non-zero numbers.

$T_4 = 4 \times 3 \times 4 \times 12 = 576$.

$\underline{\text{Case 5: 1 (0), pattern = 1,1,1,1,1}}$

The $0$ can be placed $4$ positions.  Once the $0$ is placed, there are $4!$ ways of placing the other numbers.

$T_5 = 4 \times 4! = 96$.

$\underline{\text{Case 6: 2 (0)'s, pattern = 2,2,1}}$

There are $(4 \times 3)$ choices for the non-zero  number that will be duplicated and then the non-zero number that will appear as a singleton.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{0,0,1,1,2\}$, then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of placing the $0$'s so that neither $0$ occupies the leftmost digit.  Once the $0$'s are placed, there are $3$ ways of placing the non-zero numbers.

$T_6 = (4 \times 3) \times 6 \times 3 = 216.$

$\underline{\text{Case 7: 2 (0)'s, pattern = 2,1,1,1}}$

There are $(4)$ choices for the non-zero  number that will be omitted.  Assuming that the numbers to be used are (for example) $\{0,0,1,2,3\}$, then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of placing the $0$'s so that neither $0$ occupies the leftmost digit.  Once the $0$'s are placed, there are $3!$ ways of placing the non-zero numbers.

$T_7 = 4 \times 6 \times 3! = 144.$

---

Final computation :
$$T_1 + \cdots + T_7 = 360 + 240 + 144 + 576 + 96 + 216 + 144 = 1776.$$